# Cluster markers in AmCharts 4 maps

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4, am4maps

I have an am4maps chart with certain data points as custom HTML markers. When there are multiple data points nearby, they appear quite convoluted. It would be great if there's a way to group or cluster the markers at a certain zoom level, and then de-group or show the individual points when zoomed in.

For example, there seems to be a lot of closely related points in South-East Asia:

```
const pins = [{
  "title": "Singapore",
  "lat": 1.233,
  "lng": 103.739,
  "value": 5
}, ....
]

// Initialise am4maps and populate the series

const imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());
const imageSeriesTemplate = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
const circle = imageSeriesTemplate.createChild(am4core.Circle);
// format the circle

// add a pin or marker for all the points in the array
for (const pin of pins) {
  imageSeries.addData(pin);
}
```

Similar to the [clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) that Google Maps provide. I searched the docs for AmCharts but couldn't find a helpful example.

How do I cluster the data points(or marker) in the image series, at a zoom level?

Also, how do I label the marker with a value?

Here's a working CodePen: https://codepen.io/chechs/pen/ZEEexMN

Comment: Give this plugin a try: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/plugin-overlap-buster/

Comment: Thanks, but the plugin doesn't remove the overlaps and only triggers on hover

Comment: Found this tutorial that helps to a greater extent: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/hide-map-images-until-zoomed-in/